# Set Default values in mysql id and timestamp column?

Tags: mysql

I want to set my id in mysql table to default value say '000001' or'TodaysDate followed by 000001'..and same should be also auto_incremented.
how can we do this?

and also how set default value in TIMESTAMP column not by using 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
such as '2012-04-01' and when update trigger will get fire it should get updated with todays date.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I want to set my id in mysql table to default value say '000001'.

If I were you I will leave it like id int, auto increment and when make the select I'll use the lpad function:

```
mysql> select lpad('1',6,'0');
+-----------------+
| lpad('1',6,'0') |
+-----------------+
| 000001          |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

about the timestamp I'll let that someone else answer, because what I'm thinking is do the same, use the current_timestamp and with mysql function convert to it how you want to:

```
mysql> select left(now(),10);
+----------------+
| left(now(),10) |
+----------------+
| 2012-06-01     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)'
```

**EDIT:**

```
mysql> select concat(replace(left(now(),10),'-',''),lpad('1',6,'0'));
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(replace(left(now(),10),'-',''),lpad('1',6,'0')) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 20120601000001                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I din't get you

You din't tell me how to set id value to like 20120601000001

Comment: @ jcho360:what is that concat? function or

Comment: it's a function, take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: then give me table sturucture

Comment: @ jcho360 I am not getting how to do this still facing problem, please help me.

Comment: @yatin show us the structure of the table and how the result should look like, it will make easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you answered your own question: specifically you want a 'before insert/update' trigger that sets the value for you.

> CREATE TRIGGER my_autoinc BEFORE INSERT ON test1
>     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>       INSERT INTO test1 SET NEW.id_column = concat(today(), <some value>);
>     END;

Comment: this is not a solution I tried it. CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT on visitor FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO visitor SET NEW.id=concat(today(),0001);
ERROR:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN